# Is there a way to enumerate a list or dictionary that share the same index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to enumerate a list or dictionary, if the items share the same value or are equal I want them to use 1 index.

This is my code:

```
def print_data(league_results):
    for i, (team, points) in 
    enumerate(sorted(league_results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True), 1):
        if points == 1:
          i = i
        print('{}. {}, {}'.format(i, team.strip(''), points))
```

Output

```
1. Man City, 6
2. Liverpool, 5
3. Everton, 1
4. Stoke, 1
5. Fulham, 0
```

This is my desired output: If a team share a point they should have the same index. Everton & Stoke must share the same index.

```
1. Man City, 6
2. Liverpool, 5
3. Everton, 1 
3. Stoke, 1
4. Fulham, 0
```

Comment: Whats in `league_results`?

Comment: Provide an example of `league_results`

Comment: Sorry about that I have created a dictionary, I sort it first according to points then enumerate {'Man City': 6, 'Everton': 1, 'Liverpool': 5, 'Stoke': 1, 'Fulham': 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
def print_data(league_results):
    grouped_results = itertools.groupby(
        sorted(league_results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), 
        key=lambda x: x[1]
    )
    for i, (_, teams) in enumerate(grouped_results, 1):
        for team, points in teams:
            print('{}. {}, {}'.format(i, team.strip(''), points))
```

Results:

```
1. Man City, 6
2. Liverpool, 5
3. Everton, 1
3. Stoke, 1
4. Fulham, 0
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/GoldenGullibleDatamining)

Explanation:

`groupby` will make an iterable with matching between the amount of points and the teams (it will group them if they are sorted) giving us an iterable of `(points, [(team, points), ...]), ...`. Hence when enumerating it you will enumerate this groups, that will be our index `i`.
Since we want the enumeration to start from `1` instead of `0` we simply ask the function to start from it `enumerate(iterable, start_enumerate_value)`

Comment: Thank you the code works but if you can be so kind and explain to me why should I use groupby and why did you increment the index or i  in .format?